# example for having O(logn)^2 time performance

Tags: performance

Hi
Is there any example for showing some code that has O(logn)^2.
I can not get where we will have such this time performance.
thanks

Comment: Where did you seen this notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this can happen with nested [binary searches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which are `O(log n)`.

Here's a silly example, using C#:

```c#
public class SuperHeroComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        int firstLimboIndex = Limbo.BinarySearch(first);
        int secondLimboIndex = Limbo.BinarySearch(second);
        if (firstLimboIndex < 0 && secondLimboIndex >= 0) {
            return 1;
        if (firstLimboIndex >= 0 && secondLimboIndex < 0) {
            return -1;
        return String.Compare(first, second);
    }
}

public static class Continuity
{
    public static int IndexOfSuperHero(string name)
    {
        return SuperHeroes.BinarySearch(name, new SuperHeroComparer());
    }
}
```

In the code above, `Continuity.IndexOfSuperHero()` will have `O(log n)²` complexity.